# How do I write CMake install for a library?

Tags: cmake, installation, libraries, make-install, system-paths

Here is my try:

```
IF (NOT WIN32)
  #INSTALL_TARGETS(${LIB_INSTALL_DIR} ${tinyscheme-nix_BINARY_DIR}/libtinyscheme.so)
  #INSTALL(TARGETS ${tinyscheme-nix_BINARY_DIR}/libtinyscheme.so DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR})
ENDIF()
```

Both variants are wrong. I want to move `libtinyscheme.so` from `${tinyscheme-nix_BINARY_DIR}` to `/lib` or `/lib64`. Basically, I think `${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}` handles it.

How can I make it? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want the `FILES` version of `install` here instead of the `TARGETS` version.

The `TARGETS` version of `install` is used for actual CMake targets which have been added using e.g. `add_library`.  In this case, you would refer to the target by its name assigned during the `add_library` command, rather than its full path.

So replacing `TARGETS` with `FILES` in your second command would be the way to go here I think.

For full details on the `install` command, run:

```
cmake --help-command install
```

Comment: I see, seems like LIB_INSTALL_DIR doesn't work as I want it to

Comment: @Sholy `install` should generally just specify a path relative to [`${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.8/cmake.html#variable:CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX), so if you set `${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}` to "lib" or "lib64" as appropriate, and leave `${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}` set to its default, the library will end up in /usr/local/lib or /usr/local/lib64.

Comment: @Fraser your comment indicates some deep cmake insights, however I have a few more questions about `${LIB_INSTALL_DIR}`, which I put [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36723588/258418). Some further insights would be very much appreciated.