# CMake best practice for library install

Tags: cmake, shared-libraries

I am trying an install script for a shared library with cmake. While I found out that I want to use `install`, I am not sure what's the best practice to set the destinations.

[This comment*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10928305/258418) and [various](https://code.google.com/archive/p/libhsplasma/issues/73) [bugreports](https://git.reviewboard.kde.org/r/120933/) refer to `LIB_INSTALL_DIR`.

However I find hardly any documentation of the `LIB_INSTALL_DIR`

My best guess for a library install would be:

```
add_library(mylib SHARED ${sources})
install(TARGET mylib LIBRARY DESTINATION ${LIB_INSTALL_DIR})
install(FILES ${libheaders} DESTINATION ${??})
```

My questions regarding this are:

1. How do I set `LIB_INSTALL_DIR` in a way that the user can overwrite it if requires (`set LIB_INSTALL_DIR lib)` does not allow this, does it?)
2. What is the correct variable for the header directory? (Should I try to default it (set it to that if it is undefined) to `CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH`, and if so how do I do that?)
3. `install(TARGET` has a `INCLUDES DESTINATION`, is there a better way than using manual `install(FILES ${libheaders} DESTINATION ${??})` for a bunch of headers?

*first comment, by [Fraser](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2556117/fraser), could not find a way to link directly to the comment, only to the answer.

Comment: One question per question post, please. It is OK to ask related questions in the one post, but your questions have a little common aside from being CMake-related.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the way I see it, the question list clarifies my actual problems with the main question which is "What is the best practice for installing a shared library (library and headers) with cmake". But I will keep this in mind and doublecheck if I can split my questions before I post another one.

Comment: Actually, your first question has nothing common with "best practice for installing...". It is just technical and can be answered as `Use CACHE keyword for make variable overwritable by the user`. Your third question is also technical: `INCLUDE DESTINATION` doesn't install anything but add interface for possibly exported target. For install many files in similar scenario you may use `foreach` loop over list of files. Only the second question is related to "best practice" about choosing destination paths. Having many questions in the one post contradicts **Question/Answer** nature of SO.

Comment: I highly recommend you read https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/guide/importing-exporting/index.html